# ios - check what the value is of a selected UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsstring

I need to find out what the value is of any given `cell.textlabel.text` within a `UITableView`.

The content is partly dynamic - I know what are all  the possible variations are there to show which  can be  displayed , but I do not know when certain rows are being displayed or not.

For this reason `if(indexPath.row == 1)` will not do.

Is there someway to do something like `if([indexPath.row isEqualToString:@""])` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a cell having indexPath - you do that:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@""]) { }
```

Comment: Super:-) thanks. SO will allow me to accept your answer in 10 minutes.